# How to attach json-formatted payload into RestSharp request?

Tags: c#, request, oauth-2.0, restsharp, payload

I can not put a workload in requests with RestSharp. Can anyone help me?

I tested

`request.AddBody(payload)` -> payload is a serialized object in json

But, doesn't work for me:

```
public override string Post(string url, object payload) { 
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST); 
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(payload); 
    IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request); 
    return response.Content; 
}
```

The return of method is empty string :/ :/

Comment: public override string Post(string url, object payload)
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(payload);

            IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);

            return response.Content;
        }

The return of method is empty string :/ :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a helper method that I use:

```
    private IRestRequest CreateRequest(Uri uri, Method method, object body)
    {
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(uri, method);
        request.Resource = uri.ToString();
        request.Timeout = _timeout;

        if (body != null)
        {
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.JsonSerializer = new CustomConverter {ContentType = "application/json"};
            request.AddBody(body);
        }

        return request;
    }
```

With the converter looking like this:

```
class CustomConverter : ISerializer, IDeserializer
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings;

    static CustomConverter ()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new IsoDateTimeConverter() },
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
    }

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, SerializerSettings);
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, type, SerializerSettings);
    }

    string IDeserializer.RootElement { get; set; }
    string IDeserializer.Namespace { get; set; }
    string IDeserializer.DateFormat { get; set; }
    string ISerializer.RootElement { get; set; }
    string ISerializer.Namespace { get; set; }
    string ISerializer.DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

I can then call Execute on the returned request. I'm wondering whether the serialisation needs to be done by the RestSharp framework (by setting the serialiser to use).

Answer (score 0):

Restsharp version [`105.0`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/105.0) added a new method [`IRestRequest.AddJsonBody`](https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#addjsonbody), so now you only need to call `AddJsonBody()` and it will do the rest for you:

```
request.AddJsonBody(new MyParam
{
   IntData = 1,
   StringData = "test123"
});
```